# Parallel Evaluation Stops Evaluating Without Warning Message

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

This is my full code

```
Table[data[j] =  QuantityMagnitude[
Normal[(FinancialData[(index1 = {"MSFT"})[[j]], "AdjustedClose", 
    date = {{2000, 1, 1}, {2012, 1, 1}}])["Values"]]];, {j, 1, numberOfStocks = 1}]

{test = ParallelTable[
Last[{pred = 
   Mean[{TimeSeriesForecast[
      TimeSeriesModelFit[data[1][[252*9 + i ;; 252*10 + i]], 
       "SARIMA"], 1], 
     TimeSeriesForecast[
      TimeSeriesModelFit[data[1][[252*9 + i ;; 252*10 + i]], 
       "ARMA"], 1], 
     TimeSeriesForecast[
      TimeSeriesModelFit[data[1][[252*9 + i ;; 252*10 + i]], 
       "SARMA"], 1]}], 
  pre = (pred - data[1][[252*10 + i]])/(data[1][[252*10 + i]]), 
  pre/Abs[pre]}], {i, 1, Length[data[1]] - 252*10}], Last[5000*
E^(Accumulate[
   Round[test]*
    Differences[
     Log[data[1][[252*10 ;; Length[data[1]]]]]]])]}[[2]]
```

This isn't a very intensive calculation. When I begin running it the progress bar very quickly indicates that it is going to be done soon. However when it reaches 19/20 it just stops. The time it takes to finish just continues to increase. [image] This is a very serious issue for me and can cripple my business if I can't get parallel table working properly again. The problem persists whether I use Mathematica or the Wolfram Finance platform. Any suggestions on what might be going on here would be appreciated. I'm using version 13.01.

I tried this on another machine running Mathematica 13.01. The same problem persists. I think it is a bug.

Comment: Did this ever run faster? Whatever the issue, it is not from `ParallelTable`. WHn I run sequentially it takes around 300 seconds to handle the first 480 (out of 499) iterations. Doing the full set takes around 10 times as long on the same machine. They seem to get progressively slower beginning around 488. Some experiments reveal it is the `"SARIMA` fit that gets slow.